# pyspark cluster ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ''

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using client mode in pyspark

when I run my code

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' happen

What I do

1. I set spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON option all nodes can approach
2. I made pyspark_env.tar.gz using venv-pack to use spark.archives config
3. installed all lib for my code and check

following the official doc of spark

it is the all of way to use worker node venv

why the error happen?

How can solve this?

My cluster spec

1. standalone manager
2. client mode
3. master and worker connected all I checked it in my spark ui